# Parse iOS Subclassing. Check if array field contains value

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have two classes named Event and Tag (using LocalDatabase).

```
@interface Event : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tags;

@interface Tag : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
```

`tags` field is an array of pointers to objects of `Tag` class.
I want to add a new tag to an event object and I need to check if there is no such tag in the array already. And if there is no such tag - add it.

What is the best approach to do it?

Additional question:
How can I query only objects from "tags" array (If, for example, I have several different array fields and lots of other fields and I don't want to use "includeKey")?

Edit:
As far as I understand, Array field in **Parse** contains only pointers to objects. So if I have, for example, object `event` with such fields as `tags`, `people`, `places` (which are arrays) then to get the actual data I will need to fetch `event` object using `includeKey` method. Or I can fetch the whole `event` object with all it's related data. That is what I DON'T want to do.
I want to have the array of, say, `tags` as a simple NSArray.
Something like

```
NSArray *tags = [event tags];
```

Thanks!

Comment: how big can Array grow ?

Comment: Let's say 100-200 tags.

Comment: If this checking will happen rarely you can directly use "containsObject" method of NSArray to check if there is already a tag , otherwise you can create a NSDictionary ( hashmap - hashset ) , it will be much faster to check if there is already an object or not ,

If you do not want to check if there is an object and JUST WANT to store objects but want to make sure they are unique , just use NSSet and add all the tags you want , it will store only unique tags

Comment: Yes, I just want to add a unique tag. Will Parse subclass recognise the NSSet field? Can you give me an example of how to do it in code?
BTW, what about my additional question?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can not use `containsObject` from `NSArray` class because underlying it calls the `isEqual` for each elements. In `Parse`, there has a very convenient API to add unique object and you only need to call `- (void)addUniqueObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString *)key`.

For your additional question, I think they don't have something like that without querying using `includeKey`. After that, I think `<Subclassing>` category can enable that line of code you wrote.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to create a new object, for example,
Tag *newTag = [Tag object];
newTag.name = @"#MyNewTag";
And then add it as [event addUniqueObject:newTag for Key:@"tags"];
But if there is already a tag with the same name in the array, it will be duplicated, because the objectID (I think comparison will be made with using of this field) of the tag is different.
So your solution won't work in this case. And it is my case :(

Comment: For your additional question, I just give you a hint and I am not quite sure. But I do sure that `includeKey` is the way to retrieve it. @lonlywolf